# Problema ao carregar dados de uma tabela com angularjs e api rails

Tags: json, angularjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby

**O código do meu front-end :**

```
var listaDeProdutos = function(){
    $http.get("http://localhost:3000/produtos").success(function(data,status){
        $scope.listaProdutos = data;
    }).error(function(data,status){
            console.log("error");
    });
};

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Data Vencimento</th>
                <th>Descrição</th>
                <th>Tipo Produto</th>
                <th>Preço</th>
                <th>Preço Desconto</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="produtos in listaProdutos">
                <td>{{ produtos.descricao}}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
 </div>
```

**Agora meu Back-End com Rails:**

```
def index
  @produtos = Produto.all
  render json: @produtos
end
```

**Resultado do JSON**

```
{"produtos":[{"id":1,"descricao":"teste","tipoproduto":"Carnes","preco":12.0,"precodesconto":12.0,"datavencimento":"2015-09-17"},{"id":2,"descricao":"123","tipoproduto":"Carnes","preco":12.0,"precodesconto":12.0,"datavencimento":"2015-09-17"},{"id":3,"descricao":"teste","tipoproduto":"Carnes","preco":12.0,"precodesconto":12.0,"datavencimento":"2015-09-17"},{"id":4,"descricao":"testando salvar produto","tipoproduto":"Hortifruti","preco":20.0,"precodesconto":20.0,"datavencimento":"2015-09-18"}]}
```

**Testei um Json manualmente retirando {"produtos": do meu json retornado pela api e funcionou , como faço para resolver esse problema?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O objeto `$scope.listaProdutos` precisa fazer referência direta a um array para que o ng-repeat funcione.

Substituindo a linha

`$scope.listaProdutos = data;`

por

`$scope.listaProdutos = data.produtos;`

deve resolver o problema.

Comment: Estou só de curioso aqui. Mais será que ele der um Json.Parse não funcionaria?

Comment: Eu acredito que o objeto *data* na função de sucesso dele já contenha um objeto certinho. Mas, caso venha uma String, ele deve fazer o JSON.parse, além de todo o resto.  Mas mesmo assim, o *data* por si só não seria um array. Na verdade, o data é um objeto que contém um array chamado *produtos*.

Comment: Vdd +1, boa resposta.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno o problema resolveu :)